# PL/SQL Cursor Loop Fetch to java

Tags: java, plsql, cursor

I'm working on converting a PLSQL procedure to Java/Postgres. Have a question on this logic and flow:
There are 2 select queries and a cursor loop. I'm not getting the cursor loop logic. Can someone help on that. Is it 2 for loops?

PLSQL:

```
Procedure SAM (

 TYPE RC IS REF CURSOR;
    L_CURSOR   RC;

    L_QUERY    VARCHAR2(4000);

    CURSOR L_TEMPLATE IS
        SELECT P.id                 p_id,
               Q.id                 q_id
        FROM   table1 P,
               table2 Q
        WHERE  (P.id <> Q.id);

    L_REC      L_TEMPLATE%ROWTYPE;

...

 L_QUERY := 'SELECT  P.id        p_id,
                        Q.id        q_id
             from ...rest of query...';

-- Open the generic cursor and fetch into the template record
    OPEN L_CURSOR FOR L_QUERY;
    LOOP
        FETCH L_CURSOR INTO L_REC;
        EXIT  WHEN L_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
...logic...

 END LOOP;
    CLOSE L_CURSOR;
```

Thanks

Comment: PL/SQL or PL/pgSQL?

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL to java/Postgres SQL @WilliamRobertson

Comment: Ah, OK. Looks like `l_template` is just a dummy cursor used to declare record `l_rec` with the required columns and their datatypes (`l_template%rowtype`). The procedure never uses `l_template` after that.